# Sharepoint FullTextSQLQuery index will not clear

Tags: c#, .net, sharepoint

After resetting the crawled content from my shared service I can still see all of the indexed data by using a FullTextSQLQuery.  If I try searching using the OOB search on my site, I see no results, and the Props table is cleared in the database.

Any clue as to why this is happening?  I am planning to create a web part for searching using FullTextSQLQuery, and I'd like to understand this behavior.  Maybe it archives the crawled content and OOB searches ignore archives somehow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure which version of FullTextSqlQuery is being used.  Microsoft.Sharepoint.Search.Query.FullTextSqlQuery is the WSS version and (from what I can figure out) actually retrieves another index located at database=WSS_Search_XXXX path=Program Files\Microsoft Office Servers\12.0\Data\Applications\\

The MOSS version is Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Query.FullTextSqlQuery and it will use the corresponding shared service index for the site you instanciate it with.

As far as resetting the WSS index.. still not sure about that.

Comment: update: to perform a full crawl on the wss index you can use stsadm -o spsearch -action fullcrawlstart

Answer (score 0):

The index is not stored on the database but the file system.

Open central administration

1. Select your SSP from the menu on the left under "Shared Services Administration"
2. Under the search header, select "Search Settings"
3. Within the page that loads (Configure Search Settings) you can do 1 of 2 things. Either select "Reset all crawled content".

Comment: Is there a second option?  I have already reset the crawled content, as I stated in my question.

Comment: You can see the index location is search settings and clear the filesystem yourself. Make sure to do it on all index servers.

Comment: So this is normal?  Resetting the crawled content has no effect on searches performed using FullTextSQLQuery?  Need to manually delete the index files every time?

Comment: Maybe it is cached somewhere? Did you do an iisreset? I don't think you should need to delete the index files manually...

Comment: iisreset and reset my pc, no good.  I think it is somehow querying the entire farm's available indexes for some reason rather than just the corresponding shared service's index that I instanciate the query with.  My web apps all point to the same Search Server (under Manage Content Database Settings), maybe that's related.

Comment: OK, so I set that non-crawling app's seach server to none, then set it back to the same search server, and now it behaves like I'd expect it to.  Doing a query on one app gives different results from the other app, as it should.  Weird.

Comment: OK, all of that was a coincidence.  It was due to the fact that I went from the WSS version of FullTextSQLQuery to the MOSS version.